# PowerBuilder object cannot be deleted

Tags: powerbuilder

Some of the objects in a PBL (PowerBuilder library) cannot be, exported, deleted, regenerated. And library itself cannot be optimized. Even those objects cannot be edited and neither their source is opened in editor. How to get rid of those objects from the library?

PB12.5

Answer (score 1):

It happens when your source gets corrupted. Try to get backup

You may have to create a new library for the same and move all non-corrupted objects to the newly created library one by one.

Comment: I did that already. copied the corrupt object from backup and library painter shows me two objects of same type and name. One of them is corrupt and still cannot be deleted. The other i copied from backup is opened and deleted. btw, source of what? library?

Comment: I’d focus on the second paragraph and try to copy the surviving objects to a new PBL. In fact, instead of a library copy, I’d export/import to make sure you don’t copy any corrupted pointers.